# alphabetical categories list

Tags: categories, navigation, ee7

I am building out a navigation using the a category group from a channel.
It works fine, but I can't get the categories to list out alphabetically.
This is the code I have spitting it out

```
{exp:channel:categories channel='convention' category_group="3"  show_empty="no" style="linear" }
<li class="pf-c-nav__item"><a class="pf-c-nav__link {if active} pf-m-current{/if}" href="{path='convention'}">{category_name}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like the categories are ordered by their order in the backend. I moved them around and that seemed to fix it. Doesn't look there is a way to by default force them to order alphabetically though.